# Non-gregorian calendars and Globalize.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, jquery-globalization

Are non-Gregorian calendars currently supported in Globalize.js? If so, how can I convert, let's say, today's date, into a Hijri calendar equivalent?

For example, right now when I try this:

```
      Globalize.locale("ar-eg");
      var arDate =  Globalize.formatDate( new Date( 2014, 9, 24 ), { date: "long" } );
```

I get: **24 أكتوبر، 2014**

But what I really want is to get is **29 ذو الحجة‎ 1435** (or similar equivalent).

Answer (score 0):

We're working the support for non-gregorian calendars at:

- https://github.com/jquery/globalize/issues/320.
- WIP implementation at https://github.com/jquery/globalize/pull/447.